# How can I copy one cell of a Sharepoint table - without opening the details view?

Tags: css, sharepoint

How can I copy one cell of a Sharepoint Table without opening the details view?

What I've tried before:

I have tried editing a colums format with the custom JSON-format. It works perfectly for every style attribute except user-select. That means, when I add the following scheme:

```
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
"elmType": "span",
"style": {
  "font-size": "40px",
  "user-select": "text"
  }
}
```

The column shows all text with size 40px, when I inspect the DOM, the element is also visible. But the user-select style attribute is not injected into the DOM. I can also find the `user-select: none` responsible for disabling selecting text in the table. When I delete it, the text can be selected and copied just like I want it.

Is this a bug? Should I report it to Microsoft, do you have any suggestions on how to make that work or alternative ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user-select` property in `style` is not supported in SharePoint JSON formatting.

As of today, only below CSS style properties are supported in SharePoint:

```
'background-color'
'fill'
'background-image'
'border'
'border-bottom'
'border-bottom-color'
'border-bottom-style'
'border-bottom-width'
'border-color'
'border-left'
'border-left-color'
'border-left-style'
'border-left-width'
'border-right'
'border-right-color'
'border-right-style'
'border-right-width'
'border-style'
'border-top'
'border-top-color'
'border-top-style'
'border-top-width'
'border-width'
'outline'
'outline-color'
'outline-style'
'outline-width'
'border-bottom-left-radius'
'border-bottom-right-radius'
'border-radius'
'border-top-left-radius'
'border-top-right-radius'
'box-decoration-break'
'box-shadow'
'box-sizing'

'overflow-x'
'overflow-y'
'overflow-style'
'rotation'
'rotation-point'

'opacity'
'cursor'

'height'
'max-height'
'max-width'
'min-height'
'min-width'
'width'

'flex-grow'
'flex-shrink'
'flex-flow'
'flex-direction'
'flex-wrap'
'flex'
'justify-content'
'align-items'

'box-align'
'box-direction'
'box-flex'
'box-flex-group'
'box-lines'
'box-ordinal-group'
'box-orient'
'box-pack'

'font'
'font-family'
'font-size'
'font-style'
'font-variant'
'font-weight'
'font-size-adjust'
'font-stretch'

'grid-columns'
'grid-rows'

'margin'
'margin-bottom'
'margin-left'
'margin-right'
'margin-top'

'column-count'
'column-fill'
'column-gap'
'column-rule'
'column-rule-color'
'column-rule-style'
'column-rule-width'
'column-span'
'column-width'
'columns'

'padding'
'padding-bottom'
'padding-left'
'padding-right'
'padding-top'

'bottom'
'clear'
'clip'
'display'
'float'
'left'
'overflow'
'position'
'right'
'top'
'visibility'
'z-index'

'border-collapse'
'border-spacing'
'caption-side'
'empty-cells'
'table-layout'

'color'
'direction'
'letter-spacing'
'line-height'
'text-align'
'text-decoration'
'text-indent'
'text-transform'
'unicode-bidi'
'vertical-align'
'white-space'
'word-spacing'
'hanging-punctuation'
'punctuation-trim'
'text-align-last'
'text-justify'
'text-outline'
'text-overflow'
'text-shadow'
'text-wrap'
'word-break'
'word-wrap'

'stroke'
'fill-opacity'

'--inline-editor-border-width'
'--inline-editor-border-style'
'--inline-editor-border-radius'
'--inline-editor-border-color'

'-webkit-line-clamp'

'object-fit'
'transform' // Only translate(arg) and translate(arg, arg) are currently supported
```

**Microsoft Official Documentation**: [SharePoint JSON formatting syntax reference - style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#style)

Answer (score 0):

An optional property that specifies style attributes to apply to the element specified by . This is an object with name-value pairs that correspond to CSS names and values. The values of each property in the style object can either be a string (including special strings) or an Expression object. The following style attributes are allowed.

```
'background-color'
'fill'
'background-image'
'border'
'border-bottom'
'border-bottom-color'
'border-bottom-style'
'border-bottom-width'
'border-color'
'border-left'
'border-left-color'
'border-left-style'
'border-left-width'
'border-right'
'border-right-color'
'border-right-style'
'border-right-width'
'border-style'
'border-top'
'border-top-color'
'border-top-style'
'border-top-width'
'border-width'
'outline'
'outline-color'
'outline-style'
'outline-width'
'border-bottom-left-radius'
'border-bottom-right-radius'
'border-radius'
'border-top-left-radius'
'border-top-right-radius'
'box-decoration-break'
'box-shadow'
'box-sizing'

'overflow-x'
'overflow-y'
'overflow-style'
'rotation'
'rotation-point'

'opacity'
'cursor'

'height'
'max-height'
'max-width'
'min-height'
'min-width'
'width'

'flex-grow'
'flex-shrink'
'flex-flow'
'flex-direction'
'flex-wrap'
'flex'
'justify-content'
'align-items'

'box-align'
'box-direction'
'box-flex'
'box-flex-group'
'box-lines'
'box-ordinal-group'
'box-orient'
'box-pack'

'font'
'font-family'
'font-size'
'font-style'
'font-variant'
'font-weight'
'font-size-adjust'
'font-stretch'

'grid-columns'
'grid-rows'

'margin'
'margin-bottom'
'margin-left'
'margin-right'
'margin-top'

'column-count'
'column-fill'
'column-gap'
'column-rule'
'column-rule-color'
'column-rule-style'
'column-rule-width'
'column-span'
'column-width'
'columns'

'padding'
'padding-bottom'
'padding-left'
'padding-right'
'padding-top'

'bottom'
'clear'
'clip'
'display'
'float'
'left'
'overflow'
'position'
'right'
'top'
'visibility'
'z-index'

'border-collapse'
'border-spacing'
'caption-side'
'empty-cells'
'table-layout'

'color'
'direction'
'letter-spacing'
'line-height'
'text-align'
'text-decoration'
'text-indent'
'text-transform'
'unicode-bidi'
'vertical-align'
'white-space'
'word-spacing'
'hanging-punctuation'
'punctuation-trim'
'text-align-last'
'text-justify'
'text-outline'
'text-overflow'
'text-shadow'
'text-wrap'
'word-break'
'word-wrap'

'stroke'
'fill-opacity'

'--inline-editor-border-width'
'--inline-editor-border-style'
'--inline-editor-border-radius'
'--inline-editor-border-color'

'-webkit-line-clamp'

'object-fit'
'transform' // Only translate(arg) and translate(arg, arg) are currently supported
```

As we could see, "user-select" is not contained among the styles.

Comment: Where did you get that list from? Could you please add your source?